# Sync project in android studio failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm totally new in android programming and by now just trying to run a "Hello World" program! But I couldn't! This is what I've done till now:

Previously I had android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows installed on my laptop, and I installed all SDK Tools from SDK manager. But every time I wanted to sync a project it end up with this error:

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0. Searched
>   in the following locations:
>     - file:/C:/Users/Pro/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
>     - file:/C:/Users/Pro/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
>     - file:/C:/Users/Pro/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
>     - file:/C:/Users/Pro/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
>     - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
>     - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
>   Required by:
>       project : Open File

then I updated my android studio to android-studio-ide-191.5791312-windows32, and again it get that error! so I download android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01 and gmaven_stable from android developer site and as the site said, I extracted them and copy the content into [my home directory]\.android\manual-offline-m2. and then restart android studio, but the problem still exist!

Then I went to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle and checked the "Offline work" and specified the "Service directory path" as "[my home directory]/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01" and again tried to sync the project, but sync got new error:

> ERROR: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 available
>   for offline mode.

now I'm totally confused and don't know what should I do to solve this problem! If anybody help me I will really appreciate that.

Comment: preferences (settings) -> search for offline -> uncheck the box

Comment: i tested that too, but it doesn't worked either!

Answer (score -1):

Open android studio go to your project -> build.gradle -> edit this code

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
}
```

Try lowering your build.gradle version to **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'**

I think your android studio does not support that kind of classpath version.

Comment: it doesn't work too! ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.jar
Required by:
    project :
Open File

Comment: There are 2 build.gradle file make sure you edited the correct one

Comment: i edit the one whom has this comment as description at the top of itself: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

Comment: Does you gradle look like this?     

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    }

Comment: I also have the same error before but I fixed it by lowering my build.gradle version classpath, try making it more lower **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'**

Comment: try this one in gradle-wrapper.properties you should change the distributionUrl: into

**https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip**

Comment: it doesn't work! ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
Open File

Comment: along with these repositories can you add  `mavenCentral()`  and check.also try disabling proxy if any.